# Search Results to show URL as one link

Tags: search-results

I've setup a search directory in SP2013, users are requesting to have links from a list in the search results. The links show up in the hover box but it's showing the whole URL. Is there a way to show a "Link" instead of the whole URL in search results?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "Search Directory"? Do you mean search center or something else? Links to search results should show in the search result item template by default. Can you show a screen shot of what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the search result template. Create custom managed properties and consume the same.

Here is good post on how to turn your own custom column to appear in search results. http://www.abelsolutions.com/totm/creating-customized-search-results-in-sharepoint-2013/